# Win32 installers: is there a way to write to HKU startup for each user?

Tags: inno-setup, nsis, advanced-installer

Is there a Windows installer that will add to startup for each user like
`<user>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
for each user on the system? I can't write to HKLM because the program being installed is hardcoded to work with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` when toggling the start-on-login preference.

I'm also wondering how to deal with the situation where a user is created after the application is installed. Is there a place where I can put a key in a default registry profile?

Also what installer do you guys use? NSIS? Inno Setup? Advanced Installer?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has a thing called [Active](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/04/active-setup-explained/) [Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aruns_blog/archive/2011/06/20/active-setup-registry-key-what-it-is-and-how-to-create-in-the-package-using-admin-studio-install-shield.aspx), it allows you to "runonce" something for each user on the machine.

NSIS has a helper script called [EnumUsersReg](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EnumUsersReg), it does its best to give you access to all HKCUs on the local machine as long as you have administrator rights.

To set defaults for a new user, load and edit the [correct ntuser.dat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx).

Comment: This appears to be the best answer. I'm going with Active Setup.

Answer (score 2):

A setup can not reliably write to any other users profile.

Having said that, I beleive Windows installer and Windows 7 introduced a way to specify settings that are to be applied to all subsequant users.

This will NOT work in a non MSI based installer without something running for every user login from here to eternity.