# Set RunOnce for every user

Tags: c#, wix, runonce

I have an application that contains some dlls and 3 exes. I need to set an exe as RunOnce for every user. If a new user is created then the exe should run on first login of that user also. How can I set RunOnce for each user. I am using VS2015 and Wix 3.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't help you with how to set registry values wih Wix, ...

But to assure that every new user gets your RunOnce you need to set it to the default user. See the links in [Win32 installers: is there a way to write to HKU startup for each user?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288080/3090544). And [How do you get the Default Users folder (e.g. c:\users\Default)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107373/how-do-you-get-the-default-users-folder-e-g-c-users-default)